# Java upgrade with Caucho Hessian v3/v4

Tags: java, hessian

**Problem:**
We are currently using Caucho Hessian 3.2.0 in combination with Java 8 and Java 11 applications. This works fine, but we want to migrate to Java 17 and we get following systen.out message:

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private java.lang.String java.lang.StackTraceElement.classLoaderName accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @78e03bb5
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.JavaDeserializer.getFieldMap(JavaDeserializer.java:299)
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.JavaDeserializer.<init>(JavaDeserializer.java:77)
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.StackTraceElementDeserializer.<init>(StackTraceElementDeserializer.java:60)
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.SerializerFactory.<clinit>(SerializerFactory.java:627)
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.AbstractHessianOutput.findSerializerFactory(AbstractHessianOutput.java:95)
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.Hessian2Output.writeObject(Hessian2Output.java:486)
    at Main.serializeWithHessian(Main.java:23)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

There is a work-around by adding the following JVM param:

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

We dont want to use this flag in all our productive applications, so we tried to upgrade Hessian to its newest version 4.0.66.
Basicly this works for the most common use cases but doesn't work when we serialize data having same object instances multiple times.

I created a small example application: https://github.com/MatWein/hessian-test

This application reads some java serialized test data from its classpath and tries to serialize and deserialize it with Hessian.
If you run this application using Hessian 3.2.0 it works for all Java versions (8, 11 and 17 if you set the JVM flag above) in run&debug modes.
But I cannot get it work with Hessian 4.0.66 because following error occures:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.caucho.hessian.io.HessianFieldException: de.test.TestData.field29: de.test.PaymentType cannot be assigned from null
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.FieldDeserializer2FactoryUnsafe.logDeserializeError(FieldDeserializer2FactoryUnsafe.java:538)
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.FieldDeserializer2FactoryUnsafe$ObjectFieldDeserializer.deserialize(FieldDeserializer2FactoryUnsafe.java:169)
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.UnsafeDeserializer.readObject(UnsafeDeserializer.java:237)
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.UnsafeDeserializer.readObject(UnsafeDeserializer.java:148)
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.Hessian2Input.readObjectInstance(Hessian2Input.java:2202)
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.Hessian2Input.readObject(Hessian2Input.java:2123)
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.CollectionDeserializer.readLengthList(CollectionDeserializer.java:93)
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.Hessian2Input.readObject(Hessian2Input.java:2050)
    at Main.deserializeWithHessian(Main.java:32)
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 13 out of bounds for length 13
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:361)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.Hessian2Input.readObject(Hessian2Input.java:1810)
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.FieldDeserializer2FactoryUnsafe$ObjectFieldDeserializer.deserialize(FieldDeserializer2FactoryUnsafe.java:165)
    ... 8 more
```

ATTENTION: We have a different runtime behaviour between running and debugging the app (dont know why, but Hessian seems to use Unsafe class, Weak&Soft references and so on).

For me, it looks like an internal bug in Hessian. It is using the class com.caucho.hessian.util.IdentityIntMap on serialization site, but when deserializing the client cannot find the object reference index.

**Question:**
Is there any way to get Hessian 4.0.66 working with Java 8, 11 and 17 (or at least with Java 11 and 17)?

Comment: You should provide a minimal reproducing test. We don't know where input.dat comes from, and your `TestData` class has way too many fields...

Comment: Are you sure that the dat file correct? I mean to say does it contain corrupted data?

Comment: Did you inherite of ArrayList in your own class that you desserialize ?

Comment: I use the dat file because this reproduces a more complex case that we have in production. Not every input data is causing the problem and I dont know how to reproduce it with "minimal" data because I dont know the exact problem.

Comment: if the dat file were corrupted it would crash before hessian serialization

Comment: inputData is a java serialized HashSet. So no, it doesnt extend from ArrayList

Comment: "different runtime behaviour" means that it makes a difference if you run the example app by clicking "Run" in IDEA or "Debug". depending on the used java version and hessian version, you get different results in this modes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, found the issue after lot of debugging. The issue is with Enum fields having `null` values.

In Hessian `3.x.x`, it is allowing de-serialization of `null` value by default for Enum type as checked.

But in Hessian `4.x.x`, they have changed the approach of evaluating enum values and didn't allow the de-serialization of `null` value for Enum type as checked.

**Note:** I have used **4.0.66** Hessian. It will work with all versions of (JDK 8, 11, 17) (already tested)

**Fix:**

1. **First solution:** use `transient` keyword for `PaymentType`, `GenderType` & `ActivationState` as they are coming with `null` values and should be avoided being part of de-serialization.

**Note:** Before putting `transient` for Enum fields, please make sure to select fields that you think are not needed as part of serialization and you are sure that data will be coming as null for those Enum fields when de-serialization will happen.

```
public class TestData implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8316361431446795589L;

    private transient ActivationState field18;
    private transient PaymentType field29;
    private transient GenderType field34;


    ... // getters and setters
}
```

**Output with JDK 11:**

```
/Users/anisb/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-11.0.19/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=59693:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/anisb/hessian-test/target/classes:/Users/anisb/.m2/repository/com/caucho/hessian/4.0.66/hessian-4.0.66.jar Main
[de.test.TestData@12f41634, de.test.TestData@7a3d45bd, de.test.TestData@87f383f, de.test.TestData@e720b71, de.test.TestData@27f723, de.test.TestData@612fc6eb, de.test.TestData@4d3167f4, de.test.TestData@4923ab24, de.test.TestData@50d0686, de.test.TestData@1a3869f4, de.test.TestData@3aeaafa6, de.test.TestData@13c27452, de.test.TestData@1060b431, de.test.TestData@7b69c6ba, de.test.TestData@46daef40, de.test.TestData@a38d7a3, de.test.TestData@11758f2a, de.test.TestData@5ed828d, de.test.TestData@670b40af, de.test.TestData@44c8afef, de.test.TestData@262b2c86, de.test.TestData@ed9d034, de.test.TestData@612679d6, de.test.TestData@76a3e297, de.test.TestData@4eb7f003, de.test.TestData@371a67ec, de.test.TestData@63440df3, de.test.TestData@6121c9d6, de.test.TestData@77f99a05, de.test.TestData@5f3a4b84, de.test.TestData@eafc191]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Output with JDK 8:**

```
/Users/anisb/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=59763:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/anisb/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Users/anisb/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Users/anisb/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Users/anisb/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Users/anisb/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Users/anisb/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Users/anisb/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Users/anisb/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Users/anisb/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Users/anisb/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Users/anisb/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Users/anisb/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Users/anisb/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Users/anisb/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Users/anisb/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Users/anisb/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Users/anisb/hessian-test/target/classes:/Users/anisb/.m2/repository/com/caucho/hessian/4.0.66/hessian-4.0.66.jar Main
[de.test.TestData@7fbe847c, de.test.TestData@442d9b6e, de.test.TestData@4c98385c, de.test.TestData@1c655221, de.test.TestData@1b9e1916, de.test.TestData@1edf1c96, de.test.TestData@368102c8, de.test.TestData@1963006a, de.test.TestData@4f8e5cde, de.test.TestData@5eb5c224, de.test.TestData@1b701da1, de.test.TestData@58d25a40, de.test.TestData@53e25b76, de.test.TestData@ee7d9f1, de.test.TestData@3f8f9dd6, de.test.TestData@45fe3ee3, de.test.TestData@6996db8, de.test.TestData@759ebb3d, de.test.TestData@73a8dfcc, de.test.TestData@7e774085, de.test.TestData@504bae78, de.test.TestData@ba8a1dc, de.test.TestData@ea30797, de.test.TestData@4cdf35a9, de.test.TestData@17d10166, de.test.TestData@484b61fc, de.test.TestData@726f3b58, de.test.TestData@3b764bce, de.test.TestData@aec6354, de.test.TestData@15615099, de.test.TestData@5fcfe4b2]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Output with JDK 17:**

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=59813:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/anisb/hessian-test/target/classes:/Users/anisb/.m2/repository/com/caucho/hessian/4.0.66/hessian-4.0.66.jar Main
[de.test.TestData@12bb4df8, de.test.TestData@11028347, de.test.TestData@39a054a5, de.test.TestData@2f333739, de.test.TestData@1f89ab83, de.test.TestData@14899482, de.test.TestData@3caeaf62, de.test.TestData@7382f612, de.test.TestData@21588809, de.test.TestData@2a33fae0, de.test.TestData@7b3300e5, de.test.TestData@71bc1ae4, de.test.TestData@6ed3ef1, de.test.TestData@77468bd9, de.test.TestData@e73f9ac, de.test.TestData@383534aa, de.test.TestData@311d617d, de.test.TestData@7b1d7fff, de.test.TestData@61064425, de.test.TestData@16f65612, de.test.TestData@6bc168e5, de.test.TestData@3b192d32, de.test.TestData@2437c6dc, de.test.TestData@2e5c649, de.test.TestData@707f7052, de.test.TestData@299a06ac, de.test.TestData@7c53a9eb, de.test.TestData@1055e4af, de.test.TestData@2aae9190, de.test.TestData@ed17bee, de.test.TestData@136432db]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

2. **Second solution:** Make sure to send the non-null values in those appropriate Enum fields to avoid facing the below error.

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" com.caucho.hessian.io.HessianFieldException: <package>.<Class>.<field-name>: <package>.<Enum> cannot be assigned from null
   ```

**Update:**

3. **Third Solution:** I found a way to fix the issue without a code change. After adding `jackson-databind` dependency in pom.xml of the app, Hessian surprisingly started to deserialize with `null` values for Enum type.

Just add this dependency in **POM**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>{{version}}</version>
</dependency>
```

4. **Forth Solution:** You can use `@HessianUnshared` (that you suggested) annotation will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But in my data model it is a valid case to have null values in these enum fields because they are optional. So this is an hessian bug? Is there a possibility to change the hessian code to the old behaviour? because we have hundrets of different data models in our productive appllication. So we cannot edit each of it. And are you sure it is caused by enum null values? Because if you add @HessianUnshared on the TestData class it works well.

Comment: @MatWein I'm 100% sure that it has happened due to null values in enum. I guess it's not the bug on Hessian. It's just that they have changed the logic approach in later version as checked in byte code. Older jar uses JDK5 whereas newer jar uses JDK 7 with change in logic completely.

Comment: @MatWein I just tested your code as it is with the latest version of Hessian and found out the root cause.

Comment: @MatWein `@HessianUnshared` annotation is allowing null values in the enum using 4.0.66.

Comment: @MatWein That's why, you didn't get any error with `@HessianUnshared`.

Comment: @MatWein See my updated answer. I found another way with zero code change.

Comment: @MatWein See the third solution

Comment: The third answer sounds interesting. I will give it a try at monday. Can you explain how you found this solution and why it changes the behaviour of hessian?

Comment: @MatWein I was experimenting with Hessian by adding Jackson. Let me check how it worked.

Comment: @MatWein Have you tried the approach from third solution?

Comment: I tried to add the jackson dependency, but unfortunately it still crashes with Hessian 4.0.66. The fourth solution is also no option because it increases memory usage a lot and we would have to make changes to houndrets of model classes.

Comment: @MatWein Checking again. Can you tell me what error you got when you added Jackson dependency.

Comment: @MatWein Can you tell me what error you got when you added Jackson dependency.

Comment: Same as above/before: com.caucho.hessian.io.HessianFieldException: de.test.TestData.field18: de.test.ActivationState cannot be assigned from null Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 80 out of bounds for length 61

Comment: @MatWein Checking again. It should have worked. I tested it.

Comment: @MatWein Which JDK version you have used at time of this error?

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_362"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_362-8u372-ga~us1-0ubuntu1~22.04-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.362-b09)

openjdk version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.19+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.19+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04.1)

openjdk version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.7+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04.2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255496/discussion-between-anish-b-and-matwein).